# How do I put a <span> into a list of <li>?

Tags: javascript, appendchild, getelementsbytagname

Suppose there is a list of li element and i am trying to put a span tag with text node after the original text.

The method i think of is to construct a for loop to get into each of the li tag, construct my span tag by appendchild the textnode in it, then appendchild the span in each of the lif tag. It failed. Do you guys have any idea on how to dix it?

My approach (failed):

```js
const myNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

for (let i = 0; i < myNodelist.length; i++) {
  var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
  var crossSign = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
  span.appendChild(crossSign);
  span.className = "close";
  myNodelist[i].appendChild(span);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li>two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  <li>four</li>
</ul>
```

Expected result:

```
<ul>
   <li>one <span>\u00D7</span> </li>
   <li>two <span>\u00D7</span> </li>
   <li>three <span>\u00D7</span> </li>
   <li>four <span>\u00D7</span> </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Works fine here: https://jsfiddle.net/2kzjuLfr/

Comment: What’s wrong with your approach? It works fine in the snippet.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const myNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("li");

for (let i = 0; i < myNodelist.length; i++) {
   var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
   span.textContent = "\u00D7"; 
   span.className = "close";
   myNodelist[i].textContent += ' ';
   myNodelist[i].appendChild(span);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use innerHTML to do this task .

```js
const myNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (let i = 0; i < myNodelist.length; i++) {
   myNodelist[i].innerHTML += "<span>\u00D7</span>"; 
}
```

This should solve.

Answer (score 0):

I got it working without changing anything:

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
   <li>one</li>
   <li>two</li>
   <li>three</li>
   <li>four</li>
</ul>


<script>const myNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (let i = 0; i < myNodelist.length; i++) {
   var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
   var crossSign = document.createTextNode("\u00D7");
   span.appendChild(crossSign);
   span.className = "close";
   myNodelist[i].appendChild(span);
}</script>
</body>
```

Here I used innerHTML to insert some html

```html
<!doctype html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
   <li>one</li>
   <li>two</li>
   <li>three</li>
   <li>four</li>
</ul>


<script>const myNodelist = document.getElementsByTagName("li");
for (let i = 0; i < myNodelist.length; i++) {
   var span = document.createElement("SPAN");
   span.innerHTML=" testing" //you could also use innerText
   span.className = "close";
   myNodelist[i].appendChild(span);
}</script>
</body>
```